# Azure AD Security and Multi factor authentication Token - Regarding Accessible Claims

Tags: azure, authentication, token, azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

I have a question about the tokens regarding Azure AD and multi-factor authentication (MFA).

So I have managed to look into what happens with tokens when they are sent for a user with and without MFA enabled.

What I observed is that in the payload of the token there is an extra claim in the: `"amr": []` tag.  By default there is a 'pwd' in that object, but with MFA there is also a claim called 'mfa'.

So now I know that somehow the token gets modified depending on the enabled options.

Is there some other claim or mechanism to obtain a specific ID for the device that the token was issued to. A device ID that potentially relates to its regustration through "Workplace Join" in Azure AD or through the Microsoft Authenticator App?

Is there a separate token being sent related to the Application Pass that is continuously talked about in the forums and documentation?

--------------------------Update---------------------------------

Ok so reading the application password, it's basically used as another form of authenticating the multi-factor authentication. And I guess it gets stored both on Azure AD and also on the phone somewhere inside the Authentication app.

So another question, is it possible to access this password from code?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such claim about the device information in the id_token issued by Azure AD. You can refer all the claims in id_token from links below:

[Azure AD token reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-token-and-claims)

[Azure Active Directory v2.0 tokens reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-tokens)

> is it possible to access this password someone from code?

As far as I know, there is no such API like Azure Graph REST we can retrieve the password. And if you any suggestion about MFA, you can submit them from link [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory).